# Update State of a Single React Child Component in an Array of Components?

Tags: reactjs

So far, I have the expand/collapse all functionality to show/hide the Title components when clicking on the expand/collapse all buttons.

The Container component is the outer most component and maintains the openAll state which passes down to the Text components as a props.

As you can see, in the render method of the Container component, I'm returning a div nested with Button components, and array of titles (which is a div nested with a Toggle and Title components).

My biggest problem is how do I set the state of a single Title component when clicking on the Toggle component? Both the Title and Toggle components are on the same level. I have tried using a callback from the parent (Container component), but it is not working for me.

If you look at the onToggle method inside the Container, I commented out the code because this will show/hide all Title components at once instead a single one...this is because it is in an array.

The Title component has isOpen state, and it is being set by the parent's props (Container component - openAll) when the component receives the next props.

Maybe I overthinking this and making hard than it seems.

Initial App Component:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Container text="Text" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Container Component:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      openAll: true,
    };
    this.onExpandAll = this.onExpandAll.bind(this);
    this.onToggle = this.onToggle.bind(this);
  }
  render(){
    const titles = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      titles.push(
        <div key={i}>
          <Toggle text="Toggle" onToggle={this.onToggle} />
          <Title
            onToggle={this.onToggle}
            openAll={this.state.openAll}
            text={this.props.text + ' ' + i} />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Button text="Expand All" onExpandAll={() => this.onExpandAll(true)}  />
        <Button text="Collapse All" onExpandAll={() => this.onExpandAll(false)} />
        {titles}
      </div>
    );
  }

  onToggle() {
    //this.setState({
      //openAll: true
    //});
  }

  onExpandAll(isAllOpen) {
    this.setState({
      openAll: isAllOpen
    });
  }
}
```

Title Component:

```
class Title extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          isOpen: true
        }
      }

      componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
          isOpen: nextProps.openAll ? true : false
        })
      }

      render(){
        return this.state.isOpen ? <h3 style={{display: "inline-block"}}>{this.props.text}</h3> : null;
      }
    }
```

Toggle Component:

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <button onClick={this.props.onToggle}>{this.props.text}</button>
  }
}
```

Button Component:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <button onClick={this.props.onExpandAll}>{this.props.text}</button>
  }
}
```

The HTML would look like this:

```
Expand All | Collapse All 

Toggle Text 0
Toggle Text 1
Toggle Text 2
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend **adding a another component** that *contains* both the `Title` and the `Toggle` components.  Let's call this component <**`TitleToggleContainer`**>

`TitleToggleContainer` will be responsible for the state of isOpen and will *conditionally* render the child Title component accordingly.

The `Toggle` child component will set the `isOpen` state *independently* of the change to `setState` made within `componentWillReceiveProps` so only its sibling `Title` will be affected by the local change to `isOpen`.

Amended *Container* component:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      openAll: true,
    };
    this.onExpandAll = this.onExpandAll.bind(this);
    this.onToggle = this.onToggle.bind(this);
  }
  render(){
    const titles = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      titles.push(
        <TitleToggleContainer 
          key={i}                       // NOTICE how onToggle is no longer passed in,
          isOpen={this.state.openAll}   // ONLY openAll is passed in as a prop `isOpen`
          text={this.props.text + ' ' + i} 
        /> 
      );
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Button text="Expand All" onExpandAll={() => this.onExpandAll(true)}  />
        <Button text="Collapse All" onExpandAll={() => this.onExpandAll(false)} />
        {titles}
      </div>
    );
  }

  onToggle() {
    this.setState({    // this is ok to uncomment, 
      openAll: true    // it won't be used in TitleToggleContainer
    });
  }

  onExpandAll(isAllOpen) {
    this.setState({
      openAll: isAllOpen
    });
  }
}
```

New *TitleToggleContainer* class:

```
class TitleToggleContainer extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = { isOpen: true };
    this.localToggle=::this.localToggle;  // another way to bind a method
  }
  localToggle(){
    this.setState({ isOpen: !this.state.isOpen });
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {  // you still need this to receive 
    this.setState({                       // prop changes from parent Toggle
      isOpen: nextProps.openAll ? true : false
    });
  }
  render(){
    const titleComponent= this.state.isOpen ? <h3 style={{display: "inline-block"}}>{this.props.text}</h3> : null;
    return (
      <div>
        <Toggle onClick={this.localToggle}/>
        {titleComponent} 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I feel so dumb! I think this is the answer that I'm looking for. I need to walk away from the computer since I have been trying all day to figure this out. I will try your solution tomorrow morning, and tomorrow I will give you the correct answer. Thanks for your help! When should I pass the props in the constructor and super? Most of the time, I do not pass props at all as it still works.

Comment: No worries, I hope this has helped.  Re: props > I've passed the props to the constructor and super as a force of habit.  It is only really necessary if you reference want to reference `this.props` within the constructor.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried your solution, and it worked. I was getting confuse with the local state and "global" state for all of them. I couldn't figure out how not to make the "global" state affect one of them when clicking on a single toggle button because of the array.

Comment: You were quite close to begin with. It helps if you map out the data flow of your app (where data comes from, when/how it is altered). This way you can revisit it when you need to refresh you mind about the functionality. Either way, glad I could help